# Else break deletes variable

Tags: php, loops

I am going through a series of values checking if they are the same or different, I want to how many values at the top of the list are the same.

```
$counter=0;
while ($value<$numberOfValues){
    if($valueA == $valueB){
          $counter++;
    }else{
         break;
    }

} 

echo $counter;
```

Why does $counter always equals 0 after the break?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably because the condition is never true

Comment: Because PHP variables need a `$` to identify them: `while ($value < $numberOfValues){
    if($valueA == $valueB){
`

Comment: the values have a $, It's just an example of what I'm trying... I'll edit my code sorry

Comment: im sorry what is this ? where these $value, $numberOfValues comes from ? are you shure they are changing ?

Comment: I figured it out... that was the problem... they were coming from an sql query that was not working... sorry!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `value` and `numberOfValues` should have a `$` in front of them (`$value` and `$numberOfValues`), otherwise the `while()` loop will not run at all and `$counter` will still be `0`.